# gitignore rule doesn't work

Tags: git, gitignore

I have .gitignore file with following rules:

```
# Directories #
###############
/icecream/test.*
/icecream/_common_/*.txt
/icecream/cache/**
/icecream/include/compiled/**
/icecream/include/configure/**
/icecream/include/configure/important.php

# Confirmation files #
######################
google*.html
yandex*.html
```

And it works fine except this 2 rules:

```
/icecream/include/configure/**
/icecream/include/configure/important.php
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: are those files already tracked?

Comment: Why do you think they are not working?

Comment: One thing that's common about the rules that don't work is the folder "configure". I would check path and permissions on the folder and try again.

Comment: If you want us to figure out how to make it work, you're going to have to tell us (1) the expected result (what does "make it work" mean), and (2) the actual result (in what way is not currently not working)

Comment: Why it doesn't work? 1) I edit important.php 2) git add . + git commit + git push 3) updated important.php goes to repository. But it shouldn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files were already tracked in git. So the solution was:

```
git rm --cached icecream/include/configure/important.php
```

Thanks to Kristianmitk for the tip.